# Building a responsive navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a responsive navigation menu from an existing one, using Dreamweaver CS6.
There is my HTML:

```html
<div id="nav"><nav>
 
    <ul>
              <li class="subNav"><a href="#">PROGRAM</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="pre-summit-seminars.html">PRE-SUMMIT <br>
                     SEMINARS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="summit-program.html">SUMMIT <br>
                     PROGRAM</a></li>
                  <li><a href="other-activities.html">OTHER <br>
                     ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
                    <li><a href="registration.html">REGISTRATION</a></li>
                    <li class="subNav"><a href="#">VENUE</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="venue-accommodations.html">VENUE AND<br>
                    ACCOMMODATIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="getting-there.html">GETTING THERE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="travelling-canada.html">TRAVELLING<br>
                    TO CANADA</a></li>
                    
                  </ul>
                    
                    
                </li>
              <li><a href="documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="previous-summits.html">PREVIOUS SUMMITS</a></li>
 
                    <li><a href="partners.html">PARTNERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sponsors.html">SPONSORS</a></li>
 
                <li><a href="media.html">MEDIA</a></li>
  
                 <li class="end"><a href="http://...html" target="_self">FRAN&Ccedil;AIS</a></li>
 
      </ul>
      <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> 
    </nav></div>
```

The navigation is styled in CSS as a horizontal menu with a blue background and with two drop downs. I would like to add some code for it to open with a button in mobile screens.

There is my CSS:

```css
#nav {
 
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #051A37;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #051A37;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #051A37;
 height: auto; 
}

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
}


nav ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Pontano Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
   margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li.selected a,
nav ul li.selected a:hover {
 background-color: #051A37;
 color: #66cc99;
}


nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #66cc99;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}

nav li.subNav ul {
 display:none;
}

nav li.subNav:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position:absolute;
 
 
 
}

nav li.subNav ul li {
 
 background-color: #051A37;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 float: none;
 }
 
nav li.subNav ul li a {
 color: #FFF
 }
 
nav li.subNav ul li a:hover {
 color: #66cc99
 }
.end {
 float:right;
}
```

Can anyone please help me, I am turning in circles for days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework ? its main purpose is to develop responsive designs.

Instead of reinventing , you can save time by using already made and well tested solutions.